# Test only password on rar archive

Tags: passwords, brute-force, rar

I'm trying to do a bruteforce attack on a rar archive and I need the password-check to be as fast as possible. I call rarlab's "unrar" command line utility from my program in this way:

```
unrar t -p[password] archive.rar
```

And it works, but is extremely slow. The encrypted file inside the archive is about 300MB big, and unrar utility tells me there's a CRC error (wrong password) only after testing the whole file size. (which takes 10-15 secs)

Is there a quicker way to test just the archive password?

Comment: This should be quicker http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

[How to  crack AES-128 encryption used in WinRar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807869/how-to-crack-aes-128-encryption-used-in-winrar)

As to your question, no, there is no way to test just the password. The password is not stored in the encrypted archive file. AFAIK, any password you give, combined with the encrypted data, will produce decrypted data. In one universe or another, the decrypted data represent a valid RAR archive. CRC checks that the archive can be considered valid, if it fails, this means the universe in which the password is valid is not the same as your universe ;)

Answer (score 10):

Look with `rar l` if the archive contains more files than the "main" file you'd like to extract. There are usually .txt or .nfo files contained in the archive with few KB-s. You can then execute brute force attack to extract only the smallest file in archive with `rar -ppassword x <archive> <file>` what should be much faster.